# How to secure paypal custom buttons

Tags: php, paypal

I'm creating ecommerce website and I'm stuck at one point that is I'm using custom cart several items add in cart then total amount of all items will be sent to paypal using paypal custom buttons...

Below is my code for custom paypal button:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="you@youremail.com">';
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_' . $x . '" value="' . $product_name . '">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_' . $x . '" value="' . $price . '">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_' . $x . '" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '">  ';
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="' . $product_id_array . '">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://mywebsite.com/ecommerce/storescripts/my_ipn.php">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://mywebsite.com/ecommerce/checkout_complete.php">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Return to The Store">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="https://mywebsite.com/ecommerce/paypal_cancel.php">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - its fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

Problem is that anyone can easily be changed the price of items by using inspect element , firebug etc. My question is there anyway to secure these kind of paypal custom buttons.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: what you do is check the totals match when paypal informs you the payment is made

Comment: I grab the data from paypal using ipn script and store transaction details in my database.

Comment: well that's all you need. compare the two amounts.

Comment: How i'll compare the amounts ,  when submit button is pressed user will redirect to paypal account , there's no need to compared the amounts because fraudulent users can easily be changed the price from browsers.

Comment: you compare what they should of paid and what they actully paid

Comment: My question is how to stop them to change the custom fields from browser. I need to stop them on current site when they disturbed the the price field and didn't allow to reach the paypal payment page.

Answer (score 0):

There's **NO** way to secure that code. You can create a secure button using the button creator by PayPal or - better - using PayPal-Express with NameValuePair(**NVP**) Requests on server side.

Button generator: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_button-designer&factory_type=cart
NVP: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/

Comment: This is right and wrong. There is a way to secure that code using the `BMCreateButton` API call. But if you are going to be doing that, you are better off using `SetExpressCheckout`.